# Спецификация версии Java в .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: java, docker, gitlab, gitlab-runner

Описываю pipeline в Gitlab, как мне явно указать используемую версию Java в .gitlab-ci.yml? Можно ли это сделать, если определить свой docker-образ с нужным окружением?

Answer (score 2):

Можно указать образ с нужной версией Java. Например:

```
java-build:
  image: java:8
  script:
    - javac Example.java
    - java Example
```